# how to use -SimulateApplication tool via command line

Tags: ios-simulator

Does anyone know how to use -SimulateApplication tool via command line. As I understand it shoud load/istall .app via simulator? 
I'm setting next:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication $HOME/path to app

but nothing happen, only simulator launch

It would be great to get some advice?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with it too.. but ended up using ios-sim
here is what i had to do

```
xcodebuild -project testing.xcodeproj -target "testing" -configuration "Debug" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad" -sdk "iphonesimulator7.0" -IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks=8 build
ios-sim launch /Users/prjwl/Documents/Samples/testing/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testing.app --sdk 7.0 --stdout log.txt --timeout 60 --args $input
```

Hope it helps someone.